# How to add a width to td using its id in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<td  id="test_1"></td>
```

This is my td element inside the table element and I want to add width to it using jquery I used

```
 $('#test_' + 1).attr('width','256px');
```

But it is not working not adding width to the element nor showing any error in console

please help

Comment: It works fine. Maybe another style override width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attr` method is not designed for this usually I am doing this with `.css("width", "256px")`
EDIT: I have noticed you have added the "px" string at the end, if you remove the px from the end the `attr` should work also.